# Is it safe to unplug the data cable and power cable from my HDD and then boot up the PC?

Tags: hard-drive, fan, desktop-computer

My CPU is: Intel (R) Core i7 950 @ 3.07 GHz. I have the following BIOS: P6X58D-E version 0502.

For the last week or so; the first time I switch my PC on in the morning it is very noisy. I then shutdown the PC and start it back up again and it is ok for the rest of the day i.e. until the following day.

I cannot tell, which component is making the noise i.e. hard disk; fan; CPU fan etc just by opening the PC and listening.

I am thinking about disconnecting the hard drive before switching the PC on for the first time tomorrow morning to rule that out.  The hard drive contains data only i.e. the operating system is installed on the SSD card.  Can I just unplug the data and power from the hard disk and boot up the PC? I have backed up my PC, however I want to minimise the risk of seeing BSOD and having to spend one week plus rebuilding the PC.  I have looked here and I believe the answer is yes: https://www.wikihow.com/Remove-a-Hard-Drive

Comment: I myself would simply unplug the power and turn it on.  You will know immediately if there were any boot files on the drive.  If it won't boot, turn the power off, simply plug it back in, and turn it on again.  No, it shouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas, thanks.  So this could be the steps: 1) Unplug power from hard disk 2) Switch PC on and determine whether there is a noise 3) Wait for login screen to appear 4) Login 5) Check the HDD has disappeared from My Computer 6) Shutdown 7) Plug in HDD.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Listen to mr @spikey_richie ;)

Comment: @Señor CMasMas, I will.  The only worry I have is that the bios prompts me if it does not detect a keyboard.  I am wandering what it will do if it detects no hard drive I.e. do nothing or behave erratically.  I believe it will do nothing but I am not sure.

Comment: If you're disconnecting the boot drive, it won't boot. If you're disconnecting a storage drive, the BIOS won't care.

Answer (score 0):

Wont cause any issues, might blank out shortcuts depending on what you got on the HDD though.

Comment: Thanks.  It is a Seagate Barracuda PS-ST31000524AS.  It won't corrupt the shortcuts though - will it?

Comment: The shortcut just won't load the application, it'll say the ```.exe``` is missing.